# Looping over instance variables, how do I change them?

Tags: ruby

This one is best explained in code. Given this class:

```
class Simple
  def initialize
    @a, @b, @c = 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
  end
  attr_accessor :a, :b, :c
  def addOne()
    for i in [@a, @b, @c] do
      i += 1.0
    end
  end
end
s = Simple.new
s.addOne()
puts s.a
# outputs 0.0
```

How can I **change** `addOne()` **to actually do what it says?** (Add 1 to all vars in a for loop)

I guess that the `for i in ...` actually wraps a `i=@a` which creates a new instance of the number in `@a`. But I see no way I can loop over several instance variables and changing them in place. Note that my real class is obviously more complex. So, yes, I do want to loop over the variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because the expression `i += 1.0` increment the value of the local variable `i`, not of the related instance variable. To make it work you could do something like:

```
class Simple
  # ...
  def add_one
    [:a, :b, :c].each { |v| send("#{v}=", send(v) + 1.0) }
  end
end

s = Simple.new
s.add_one
puts s.a
# => 1.0
```

Comment: sawa's is IMO more direct, but I like this answer as it will exercise any other abstractions on the accessors (given that the OP has made the accessors available).

Answer (score 4):

```
%i[@a @b @c]
.each{|sym| instance_variable_set(sym, instance_variable_get(sym) + 1.0)}
```

Comment: Very fast. :-) What does the %i do in front of the array?

Comment: With ruby 1.9.3 this is not workking for me. It reports unknown type of string for the @a. Any clues?

Comment: It works for ruby 2.0 only. For 1.9, do `[:@a, :@b, :@c]` instead.